# Reading WORDS from a text file into an array in C

Tags: c, file, io

How do I read into an array entire words until a newline from a file that is formatted like this:

apple

grape

bananna

I want each word to be stored as a seperate value in the array, from the file. How can I do this?

Thanks all

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Ive tried alot of different stuff, but nothing has worked?

Comment: What do you mean by "Until a newline"? Newline where? After each word or at the end?

Comment: This is not a "please do my work for me" site. If you want that, you should hire a consultant. You should show what you've tried so far, and explain how it doesn't work like you'd expect, and then someone can help you fix it. We try to be helpful here, but you are expected to put some effort into it yourself, and saying "Ive tried alot of different stuff, but nothing has worked?" doesn't show any effort. "I've tried becoming a billionaire a lot of times, but nothing has worked" means nothing if my attempts have all involved sitting around and making wishes hoping they'll come true. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) function, like this

```
char word[100][100];
int i = 0;

while( fgets( word[i++], 80, file) )
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
char *my_strchr(char * string_ptr, char find)
{
    while (*string_ptr != find) {

       /* Check for end */

       if (*string_ptr == '\0')
           return (NULL);       /* not found */

        ++string_ptr;
    }
    return (string_ptr);        /* Found */
}

int words_count(char * string_ptr, char find)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*string_ptr != '\0') {

       /* Check for end */

       if (*string_ptr == find)
           ++i;       /* not found */

        ++string_ptr;
    }
    return (i+1);        /* Found */
}

int main()
{
    char line[80];      /* The input line */
    char *first_ptr;    /* pointer to the first name */
    char *last_ptr;     /* pointer to the last name */
    // char words[3][80];
    char **words;
    int cnt;

    // fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    static const char filename[] = "C:\\Diginity-Works\\LineReader\\debug\\data.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) // read a line 
    {   
        /* Get rid of trailing newline */
        line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';        
        cnt = words_count(line, ' ');

        // for the "first level"
        words = (char **) malloc(cnt * sizeof *words);

        // In the second level
        for(int i=0;i<cnt;++i)
            words[i]=(char*)malloc(80);// i assume that max word length is 80


        last_ptr = line;    /* last name is at beginning of line */
        for(int i=0; i < cnt; ++i){
            first_ptr = my_strchr(line, ' ');      /* Find space */

            /* Check for an error */
            if (first_ptr == NULL) {
                strcpy(words[i], last_ptr);
                break;
            }

            *first_ptr = '\0';  /* Zero out the slash */

            ++first_ptr;        /* Move to first character of name */
            strcpy(words[i], last_ptr);
            strcpy(line, first_ptr);
        }

        for(int i=0; i < cnt; ++i)
            printf("%d : %s \n", i, words[i]);
    }

    return (0);
}
```